# How to align the enumerate items using enumitem?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I'm writing a text and I want to save as much space as I can. I'm using the package `\usepackage{enumitem}` in order to manipulate the `enumerate` easily. In the following code there si a problem with the alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt, label=\bfseries{Problem \theenumi.-}, itemindent=*]
    \setcounter{enumi}{1}\item \blindtext
    \setcounter{enumi}{10}\item \blindtext
    \setcounter{enumi}{2}\item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly, when the counter has 2 digits, the alignment fails. How can I solve this problem? Is there another package that I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `align=left`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt, label=\textbf{Problem \theenumi.-}, itemindent=*,align=left]
    \setcounter{enumi}{1}\item \blindtext
    \setcounter{enumi}{10}\item \blindtext
    \setcounter{enumi}{2}\item \blindtext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]